# Capture Image from Camera/Gallery and Display in Activity/Fragment using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i know this is a trivial question well answered using java, but i'm sure there are new `APIs` to make things easier such as

`val getContent = registerForActivityResult(GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
    // Handle the returned Uri
}`

and

```
val takePicture = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { success: Boolean ->
    if (success) {
        // The image was saved into the given Uri -> do something with it
    }
}

val imageUri: Uri = ...
button.setOnClickListener {
    takePicture.launch(imageUri)
}
```

**Q:** How to implement the above question using kotlin and implementing the lastest `APIs` for that

PS: this is question is still valid if answers provided become depreciated or obsolete.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my code, hope this help

- Taking picture:

```
  fun takePicture() {
        val root =
               File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + File.separator)
           root.mkdirs()
           val fname = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"
           val sdImageMainDirectory = File(root, fname)
           viewModel.profileImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), context?.applicationContext?.packageName + ".provider", sdImageMainDirectory)
           takePicture.launch(viewModel.profileImageUri)
       }

  val takePicture = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { success: Boolean ->
       if (success) {
           // The image was saved into the given Uri -> do something with it
             Picasso.get().load(viewModel.profileImageUri).resize(800,800).into(registerImgAvatar)
       }
   }
```

- Select from library

```
    private val pickImages = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()){ uri: Uri? ->
            uri?.let { it ->
                // The image was saved into the given Uri -> do something with it
               Picasso.get().load(it).resize(800,800).into(registerImgAvatar)
            }
        }
```

Then call the function when press button:

```
btnSelectFromGallery.setOnClickListener {
                pickImages.launch("image/*")
            }
btnTakePicture.setOnClickListener {
                takePicture()
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Can you please explain what is the ViewModel in takePicture()?
Also Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() seems to be depricated

Comment: @alex ViewModel is the class in MVVM architecture where declared the profileImageUri value. Yes Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() depricated and you can use getExternalFilesDir() instead