# ActivityResultContracts way of making the user choose between gallery or camera to upload a picture

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I can find many answers, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524617/intent-to-choose-between-the-camera-or-the-gallery-in-android), on how to create an intent that makes the user choose between camera and gallery with Java and the older API.

However, while it's [relatively simple to do either of them via Kotlin with the new `ActivityResultContracts` API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62387789/capture-image-from-camera-gallery-and-display-in-activity-fragment-using-kotlin), I can't understand how to make the user choose between the two of them without making separate buttons for the two functions (which I would rather avoid).

How should I edit the latter linked answer's code to make the user choose from a system menu whether to use camera or gallery?

Answer (score 6):

You need to create your custom ActivityResultContract:

```
class TakePicturefromCameraOrGalley: ActivityResultContract<Unit, Uri?>() {

        private var photoUri: Uri? = null

        override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Unit?): Intent {
            return openImageIntent(context)
        }

        override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Uri? {
            if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return null
            return intent?.data ?: photoUri
        }

        private fun openImageIntent(context: Context): Intent {
            val camIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            photoUri = createPhotoTakenUri(context)
            // write the captured image to a file
            camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri)

            val gallIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            gallIntent.type = "image/*"

            // look for available intents
            val info = ArrayList<ResolveInfo>()
            val yourIntentsList = ArrayList<Intent>()
            val packageManager = context.packageManager

            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(camIntent, 0).forEach{
                val finalIntent = Intent(camIntent)
                finalIntent.component = ComponentName(it.activityInfo.packageName, it.activityInfo.name)
                yourIntentsList.add(finalIntent)
                info.add(it)
            }

            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(gallIntent, 0).forEach {
                val finalIntent = Intent(gallIntent)
                finalIntent.component = ComponentName(it.activityInfo.packageName, it.activityInfo.name)
                yourIntentsList.add(finalIntent)
                info.add(it)
            }

            val chooser = Intent.createChooser(gallIntent, "Select source")
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, yourIntentsList.toTypedArray())

            return chooser

        }

        private fun createFile(context: Context): File {
            val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(Date())
            val imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_"
            val storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) ?: throw IllegalStateException("Dir not found")
            return File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",  /* suffix */
                storageDir /* directory */
            )
        }

        private fun createPhotoTakenUri(context: Context): Uri {
            val file = createFile(context)
            return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)
            } else {
                Uri.fromFile(file)
            }
        }
    }
```

and you must have **camera permission granted** and [File provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58908053/11210096) created in order to work correctly

Comment: Just a couple questions about your code:

1. why do you just pass `gallIntent` to `Intent.createChooser()` if the goal is to make it choose between two?  


2. Is the `return intent?.data ?: photoUri` line because one intent returns data as a parameter while the other returns an uri?

Comment: 1- I guess you want to implement `Intent.createChooser()` inside of `ActivityResultContract`. 2 - Because camIntent doesn't return an intent in `parseResult`. That`s why I passed photoUri to camIntent in order to get and uri in  `registerForActivityResult()` last lambda parameter

Comment: Can you let me know how to use this class?

Comment: I've found a good way to pick from the gallery, using this guy code. So you need to override ActivityResultContract in order to specify intent type.

https://matteinn.com/posts/activityresultcontracts/