# ActivityResultContract to pick/take a photo in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, activityresultcontracts

How can i use ActivityResultContract (Kotlin) in order to pick a photo from the gallery OR to take a photo by the camera using only one button?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66441651/activityresultcontracts-way-of-making-the-user-choose-between-gallery-or-camera

Answer (score 3):

Pick an image from the gallery:

```
class TestActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        uri?.let { imageUri ->
            // Suppose you have an ImageView that should contain the image:
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri)
        }
    }

    private fun onButtonClicked() {
        getContent.launch("image/*")
    }

}
```

Be sure to use AppCompatActivity()

Comment: Hi, how can this uri be manipulated? I tried to open the image, the path is content:// 
How to convert it to file?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the image. See example in my answer that I have added, to show the image in an ImageView. If you need something else, better ask a new question.

Comment: I want to see the full path of a video I am importing from the gallery. In this uri, I get something like: content://media/external/video/media/173991 but I need /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/V_20221110_082812.mp4, for instance. How can I figure out this real path?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221353/7493938)